# Use intent to select files to read in android

Tags: java, android, csv, android-intent

Use intent to select files to read in android
I use the intent to get the file path of my choice as follows:

```
Intent inputFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
inputFile.setType("*/*");
inputFile.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(inputFile.createChooser(inputFile, "Select csv"),1010);
```

But the path received does not use FileInputStream to read it.
Eg: path received via intent is: /document/primary:File.csv
The desired path to read the file is: /storage/emulated/0/File.csv

Comment: The content scheme is uri.toString(). Dont use uri.toPath() for a path as it is no path. To read the file just open an input stream. `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());`

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_PICK` does not pick files. It picks content. You will get a `Uri` with a `content` scheme back most of the time, and there is no requirement that this be a file.

Also note that `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type and does need a `Uri` pointing where to pick from. If you want to choose by MIME type, or choose anything, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` are better choices. Those too will give you a `content` `Uri` back.

If you want a file, either:

- Do not use an `Intent`, but rather use [a file-chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35)
- As greenapps suggests, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, then write that content to some file that you control (e.g., copy the bytes to a `FileOutputStream`)

Or, just use the `InputStream` directly.